# trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]

Tags: python, python-3.6

i try to sentiment analysis with movies corpora. this typeError show every time. how can i run this code.i am use python 3.6 Version.i add a image all of my code please check it.

```
trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]
```

> TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method ....

code:

```
import nltk.classify.util`
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')

negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
posfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4
poscutoff = len(posfeats)*3/4

trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]`testfeats = negfeats[negcutoff:] + posfeats[poscutoff:]
trainfeats.to_csv('train1.csv', encoding='utf-8')`testfeats.to_csv('test1.csv', encoding='utf-8')

print ('train on %d instances, test on %d instances' % (len(trainfeats), len(testfeats)))

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
print ('accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testfeats))
classifier.show_most_informative_features()
```

Comment: Please check and update the formatting of your question, especially, the code parts. Use the code block (`{}` icon) option.

Comment: This: `negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4` produces a floating point number; print out `negcutoff` to find out. You can't use floating point numbers to index an array.